# 'ERROR: \'NoneType\' object has no attribute \'startswith\'

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

I am using  [Lambda Face Recognition and Face Detection API via RapidAPI](https://rapidapi.com/lambda/api/face-recognition-and-face-detection?endpoint=53aa3244e4b059614033ed20) and I am currently uploading an image via their api. 
Below I have 2 scenarios. Both have the same content but only one seems to work and the other one gives me an error.

The error I am getting is as follows:

```
code: 500,
error: 'ERROR: \'NoneType\' object has no attribute \'startswith\''
```

The only difference between the two is that one method pulls productId and productLink from a mongo database while the other one is hardcoded. Below is the code:

```
//pulled from db and stored in variables
let productId = product._id.toString(); //5d9ca969835e1edb64cf03d5
let productLink = product.ProductLink; //http://localhost:4000/uploads/1570544614486-test.jpg

//insert data into api
//doesn't work
myFaceDetAPI.trainAlbum(productLink, productId);

//works     
myFaceDetAPI.trainAlbum("http://localhost:4000/uploads/1570544614486-test.jpg", "5d9ca969835e1edb64cf03d5");
```

my function:

```
this.trainAlbum = (url, id)=>{
     let requestString = "https://lambda-face-recognition.p.rapidapi.com/album_train";
     let req = unirest("POST", requestString);
     let imgURL = url;
     let entryId = id

     unirest.post(requestString)
      .header("X-RapidAPI-Key", API_KEY)
      .attach("files", fs.createReadStream(createPath(imgURL)))//creates file path
      .field("album", ALBUM_NAME)
      .field("albumkey", ALBUM_KEY)
      .field("entryid", entryId)
      .end(result => {
        console.log(result.body);
      });
}
```

Questions:

1. Why is the hard-coded method working and the one which pulls data from the database is not?
2. How do I make the one work that pulls data from the database?

Comment: Could be that the data pulled from database is done asynchronously. Which would cause `myFaceDetAPI.trainAlbum` to be called before the data is retrieved.

Comment: I called it once the data has been saved into the database. and I do receive them in the function when I console.log them. Plus, they do look the same so I don't know what the problem is. Also, earlier I experienced an empty result error when I didn't convert product._id to string. So maybe it's something similar? Do I have to convert the link variable to something to make it work?

Comment: That depends. It's worth a look to see if the `productLink` is exactly the same as your hardcoded link string. Maybe do a compare `productLink  === ''http://localho..."` to see if it returns a `true` value. From there you can work out if the value needs conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that upon uploading data via the front end application would save it to the database and instantly search for the image in my image path which wouldn't exist yet, hence the error. To counter that problem, I created an async function which would delay the api call so it can give time to my program saving the image to the image path. Here is the code:

```
async function customAsyncFunc(productLink, productId){
   console.log(1)
   await delay(5000)
   console.log(2)
   myFaceDetAPI.trainAlbum(productLink, productId)
}

function delay(ms){
    return new Promise(resolve=>{
        setTimeout(resolve,ms)
    })
}

// Defined store route
productRoutes.route('/add').post(function (req, res) {
  let product = new Product(req.body);
  //save to database
  product.save()
    .then(product => {
      let productId = product._id.toString();
      let productLink = product.ProductLink;
      res.status(200).json({'Product': 'Product has been added successfully'});

      //insert data into api    
      //delay sending data to api so that image can be stored into filepath first
      customAsyncFunc(productLink, productId);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(400).send("unable to save to database");
    });
});
```